# Posting data to sever using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following data to be posted to server via my API.

```
Request Body: 
{
  "nutrients": {
    "protein": "beans",
    "fats": "oil",
    "carbohdrate": "starch"

  }
}
```

Each time I run the script, am getting the following error below

```
{"errors":[{"status":"400","code":"031","title":"payload not parseable","detail":"Invalid formatting of the request payload."},{"status":"400","code":"026","title":"payload missing","detail":"No payload describing the resource object included in the request."}]}
```

It seems that it's because am not adding the variable "nutrients" in the data array to be posted.

Can someone help me out. Below is my effort so far. Thanks

```
<?php
$url = "https://myapi_site.com/server/";  
$data = array(
        'protein' => 'beans',
        'fats' => 'oil',
        'carbohdrate'  => 'starch'          
); 
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting a PHP array which hasn't been converted to JSON... you want to post the JSON itself.  Here is how you can post the JSON string.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

You can use `json_encode` to encode the PHP array to JSON:

http://php.net/json_encode

Define your `$data` variable like so:

```
$data = array(
  'nutrients' => array(
        'protein' => 'beans',
        'fats' => 'oil',
        'carbohdrate'  => 'starch',
   ),
);
```

You can echo `$data` variable to see that it contains the right JSON data:

```
echo $data;
```

Comment: The error still persist, It seems that it's because am not adding the variable "nutrients" in the data array to be posted. is it possible to do something like $data = array(nutrients(
        'protein' => 'beans',
        'fats' => 'oil',
        'carbohdrate'  => 'starch'          
));

Comment: please we to add the nutrients as i cannot see any nutrients updates in the code

Comment: I edited my answer to have an updated variable for $data, copy and paste that into your code.  Yes, just use this `$data = array(nutrients( 'protein' => 'beans', 'fats' => 'oil', 'carbohdrate' => 'starch' ));`